# Vector vields and flows

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M$ be a smooth, compact manifold and $X:M\times[0,1]\to TM$ a smooth function with $X(p,t)\in T_pM$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Show that there is a smooth family $\{\phi_{t}:M\to M\}_{t\in[0,1]}$ of diffeomorphisms such that:
>
> \begin{cases}
>     \phi_0=id_M\\
>     X(p, t)=\left. \frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} \phi_{t+s}(p) 
> \end{cases}

Apparently I'm supposed to think in terms of flows of vector fields. But the flows them selves are varying and I really have no idea how to deal with the derivative of $\phi_{t+s}$. I also can't see why $M$ needs to be compact. I'm totally freezed here. Any sugestions? Thanks!

Comment: I think the basic idea is that $\phi_t$ is the flow of $X$ at 'time' $t$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, I've thought of that, but really don't know how to formalize it...